# Using variables of RecycleViewAdapter

Tags: java, android

I'm using a RecyclerView in my app and I want to make a counter in the `RecycleViewAdapter` class and get its value in the `MainActivity`.

I set 2 public variables and I used the debugger to see if the counter value chnages, and it does count properly.
The thing is when I check the value of the counter in the `MainActivity`, the value is 0, looks like it didn't count at all or the instance of `RecycleViewAdapter` was initialized again, but it didn't.

Hope you can help me figure this out, it's really weird.
Here is my code:

```
public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolders> {

    private List<User> userList;
    private Context context;
    public int goodCount;
    static public int badCount; 

    public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context, List<User> userList)
    {
        this.userList = userList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public RecyclerViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        RecyclerViewHolders rcv = new RecyclerViewHolders(layoutView);
        return rcv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolders holder, int position) {
        holder.tvName.setText(userList.get(position).name);
        if(userList.get(position).result.equals("good")) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.good));
            goodCount++;
        }
        else if(userList.get(position).result.equals("bad")){
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.bad));
            badCount++;
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.userList.size();
    }
}
```

This is part of `MainActivity` class, where I used recAdapter (defined in the  class, I didn't attach the whole class):

```
 final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        mainIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        userList = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, User[].class));

        recAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this ,userList);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recAdapter);
        int num = recAdapter.goodCount;

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), String.valueOf(num), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
};
```

Comment: So how often are you calling this `recAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this ,userList);` line? This will create a new instance of the Adapter, meaning a new Object in memory, with all the fields set to their initial values.  The old object will still be their until GC cleans it up. If you have multiple instances of the Adatper, `recAdapter` will just point to a one instance.

Comment: If you want the count **per item**, you need to put that variable in the ViewHolder, not the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the instance of RecycleViewAdapter initialized again but it didn't.

Umm, yes it did.

```
// Sets the value back to zero
recAdapter = new RecycleViewAdapter(MainActivity.this ,userList);
```

If you want the same adapter, you need to do it this way.

```
final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        mainIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Don't recreate the adapter, just update the data
        userList.clear();
        userList.addAll(Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, User[].class)));
        recAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        int num = recAdapter.goodCount;

        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), String.valueOf(num), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
```

However, it's not really clear why you need fields. Just make some other methods.

```
public int getGoodCount() {
    int count = 0;
    for (User u : this.userList) {
        if (u.result.equals("good")) count += 1;
    }
    return count;
}

// Assuming there is only good and bad
public int getBadCount() {
    return getItemCount() - getGoodCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the values of `goodCount` and `badCount` in your adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method. However, in your `onResponse()` method, you are creating the adapter, assigning it to the `RecyclerView`, and then immediately calling `int num = recAdapter.goodCount;`.

The adapter has not yet laid itself out or bound any of its views at this time, so `onBindViewHolder()` will not have been called yet and the counters will be zero.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling count immediately and recylerview has done not yet.Use this code get count.I tested and it works

```
 recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
             int num = recAdapter.goodCount;  
            }
        });
```